# Можно ли поставить двоеточие?

Tags: пунктуация

"Из седьмого примера добавить новый класс: скопление, движущееся в одном направлении."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Скопление, движущееся в одном направлении" – пояснение. Здесь могли бы быть добавлены слова "а именно": "Из седьмого примера добавить новый класс, а именно скопление, движущееся в одном направлении." При отсутствии слов "а именно"  выделение происходит обычно с помощью тире.

**Из седьмого примера добавить новый класс – скопление, движущееся в одном направлении.**

[Издательство «ЛИЦЕЙ](http://licey.net/free/4-russkii_yazyk/40-kurs_russkogo_yazyka_sintaksis_i_punktuaciya/stages/724-28_utochnyayuschie__poyasnitelnye_i_prisoedinitelnye_chleny_predlozheniya.html)» пишет, что иногда ставится двоеточие при пояснении, но в вашем примере я не вижу причин его ставить.